# Page numbers in MS word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word

am trying to insert the page numbers in the word document. The document contains table of content and the document contents. I wanna insert roman numerals to the page numbers before the first chapter n then normal numbers there after, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a section break.

In short... here's what you do.

Before on the page that starts your new numbering, you want to insert a section break.  (Under Page Layout ribon click on Breaks drop-down menu & click on Next Page)

Once the break is inserted... you can then go to your header or footer & add your page numbering.  While in the header/footer Design menu, you will have an option under "Page Number" to "Format Page Numbers..."  From there you can pick a different "style" (roman vs latin... and many others) as well as providing a new "Start at" number.  so the first three pages can be roman number i, ii, iii... and the next section can use latin-numbering starting at 1... and continuing on.

Because it's a section break... you can also add additional stuff before the break and the numbering will auto-adjust down-the-line.

Comment: Thanx a lot....